# Django admin view : how to control FormFields' attributes in InlineFormset, individually for each form?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

### Preface

I am implementing a *'Collection management system'* based on Django framework (currently, stable 1.4.3).
I am contriving the nice relational nature of the ORM to force some nasty "OO aspects", usage for which I tried to extract a minimal example. (disclaimer : the complete functional description would be another long and boring read, so I am not producing it unless it turns out as a design discussion).

### The extracted example

Let's imagine we loosely emulate OO using Django models. We have the **Release** model (=a Class) that can be composed of different **Attributes**(=the data members for the Class). Different **Instances**(= Objects) can then be instantiated for the same **Release**. Each **Instance** can store a value for all/some/none of the **Attribute** present in its related **Release**.
That would give us the following models :

```
#An attribute is a name, that can be given a value at instance level.
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

#A release can be compared to a class in OO :
# it's a data structure description (the attributes' list).
class Release(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    #A release is caracterized by a list of attributes
    # the same attribute can be present in several releases
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute, blank=True, null=True)

#An instance entry can be compared to an object in OO :
# it instantiates a release
# it can hold its own value for each of the attributes in this release.
#Nb : Attributes are all optional.
class Instance(models.Model):
    #the instantiated release
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release)

#Store the actual attribute-value pairs for the different instances.
class InstanceAttribute(models.Model):
    instance = models.ForeignKey(Instance)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

### The problem

It would be great to use the powerful Django admin with that approach.

- Everything works out of the box to add **Releases** and compose them with **Attributes**.
- It is getting more complicated for the **Instance** add view. (The related **Release** id can be forwarded by GET at an url of the form : *instance/add/?release=x*). When this view is loaded, we need to propose an InlineFormset of **InstanceAttribute** with :

  1. the number of forms matching the number of **Attributes** composing the related **Release**
  2. for each of these forms, the *Attribute* field should be initialized to an **Attribute** of the Release, and it's queryset restricted to show only this **Attribute**.

We can solve #1 by overriding the `ModelAdmin.get_formsets()` to return an `inlineformset_factory` with the *extra* parameter set to the desired number.
Taking a good look at the [add_view source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L924), I cannot find a good way to implement #2...

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question with a solution that is *working*, but not satisfying to say the least. I think it could also help the readers understand the problem stated above, by showing what I am trying to achieve exactly.

### Global state based solution

So the (bad) idea is to subclass the **InstanceAttribute** form that will be used by the view. It allows to override the form `__init__`, while introducing a global state with **InstanceAttributeForm** static data members.

- This global state should receive data such as the list of **Attributes** that have to be presented, as long as a **counter** of the currently constructed form (used to index the list of **Attributes**).
- The overridden `__init__` then uses those global variables to bind an attribute to each form constructed by the formset.

The code

```
class InstanceAttributeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #form_id count the initializations (to know which form is currently constructed by the formset)
    form_id = 0
    total = 0
    #the list of attributes in the instantiated release
    #it should be populated before the formset start the constructor calls
    attributes = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InstanceAttributeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #"deferred template rendering' is trying to construct 3 additional forms
        #bonus point if you can comment on the reason for this behavior  ; )
        if InstanceAttributeForm.form_id==InstanceAttributeForm.total:
            return

        attribute = InstanceAttributeForm.attributes[InstanceAttributeForm.form_id]
        self.initial = {'attribute' : attribute}
        self.fields['attribute'].queryset = Attribute.objects.filter(id=attribute.id)
        InstanceAttributeForm.form_id += 1
```

We have to initialize these global variables before we actually enter the forms' constructors, and hook the ***InstanceAttributeForm*** to the formset factory. To achieve that, we can customize **Instance** ModelAdmin :

```
class InstanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    #Responsible for re-initializing the global state each time before calling the super add_view
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        initialize_globalstate(request)
        return super(InstanceAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    #Return a formset factory specifying the exact number of required forms
    # and hooking our specialised ModelForm class.
    def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
        yield inlineformset_factory(
            Instance,
            InstanceAttribute,
            form=InstanceAttributeForm,
            can_delete=False,
            extra=InstanceAttributeForm.total)
```

For completeness, the global-state initialization procedure (called in the overridden `add_view()` above):

```
def initialize_globalstate(request):
    instantiated_release = Release.objects.get(id=request.GET['release'])

    InstanceAttributeForm.form_id = 0
    InstanceAttributeForm.attributes = instantiated_release.attributes.all()
    InstanceAttributeForm.total = len(InstanceAttributeForm.attributes)
```